# Django - 404 error for only one css file

Tags: python, django

I have this in my `base.html` template:

```
{%load staticfiles%}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bulma.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
```

And this is what I get in console when navigating on the page.

```
[21/Dec/2017 12:52:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1134
[21/Dec/2017 12:52:04] "GET /static/css/bulma.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/Dec/2017 12:52:04] "GET /static/css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1758
```

So the `app.css` doesn't load and I don't understand why because it is in the same folder ar bulma.css which as I see loads fine.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
    path(r'hap/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'martor/', include('martor.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = './static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
```

Comment: are you completely sure that the `app.css` file is located in the same place as `bulma.css`?

Comment: @N.Ivanov Apparently, I placed it myself in the static folder where 'collectstatic' adds them and that didn't work, I had to place it in myapp/static and that worked, not sure why :?

Answer (score 0):

in setting.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [("js", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js')),("css", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'css')),("images", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images')("fonts", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'fonts')),]